# Concatenate with php and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, concatenation

i have to concatenate `=>descriptif [i]= "'.$description[i].'";` 
in the loop for with this `(i=0 ; i<16 ; i++)`:

```
<?php echo 
    '<script> var descriptif = new Array ();

    </script>';
?>
```

i need this php array, to  create a jquery function. Help me ...

Comment: Please ask an actual question. And format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

Look into JSON functions for PHP, specifically [json_encode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)